# Finding local minimum and maximum and inflection point

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I need to examine and draw the graph of the function:

$${\displaystyle f\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}.$$

I have problems with local minimum and maximum. First derivative is
$$
f'\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(1+x\right)+x}{x\left(1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^{2}}.
$$

Now, I do not know how to solve $f'(x)>0$, $f'(x)<0$ and $f'(x)=0$. Any idea? What is the simplest way to do this?

A similar situation occurs with the second derivative of the function
$$\log_{x^{2}-3x+2}2.$$

I found it is:
$$f''(x)=\ln2\cdot\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}-3x+2\right)\left(2x^{2}-6x+5\right)+2\left(2x-3\right)^{2}}{\left(x^{2}-3x+2\right)^{2}\ln^{3}\left(x^{2}-3x+2\right)},$$

but how to solve $f''(x)>0$, $f''(x)<0$ and $f''(x)=0$. I suppose I don't have to know the exact values for x but how to sketch the graph without this.

Comment: I think you should find that the derivative is positive and that the function is increasing.

Comment: Hint: it is clearly positive when $x>0$ so focus on $x<0$. Then use the fact that for any $y$, $e^y\geq y$, so let $y= |x|$. Make sure to also think what happens at $x=0$.

Comment: @johnB : I think $f''(x)=\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^\frac{2}{x}}{x^3\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^3}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^3\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^2}\\=\dfrac{\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^3\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^3}$

Comment: For the first example I need $f'(x)$ and for the second example I need $f''(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint:$$f''(x)  =\begin{cases}\frac{\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^3\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^3}=\frac{(e^{+}-1)e^+}{+}>0 & x > 0\\\text{undefined} & x=0\\\frac{\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^3\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^3}=\frac{(e^{-}-1)e^-}{-}>0 & x > 0\end{cases} 
$$ so $f''>0$ and $f(x)$ is departed into two convex part for $0<x , x>0$